# Samsung Tizen Web app for testing

Tags: tizen

I'm looking for samsung tizen web. I just need it to test my sender application and would like if I don't have to create my own. Looked everywhere in the samsung documentation and wasn't able to find one available.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are exactly looking for? Are you trying to develop any Tizen Web application or what?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. No I'm creating a sender app, I just need a tizen web app to test it on.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about your application and how you want to use the web app with your sender app?

Comment: The app is casting videos but there is no further need for assistance, I created my own custom tizen web app. Anyway thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to visit here.
http://developer.samsung.com/home.do

You can also test various devices on the Remote Test Lab via the web.
http://developer.samsung.com/rtlLanding.do

It pretty good to test without real devices!